# How do we print a function's name along with the calling arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack-trace, python-decorators, signature

We want to print each function call along with the calling arguments.

Consider the following recursive function decorated with a user-defined (custom-made) decorator named `@traced`:

```python
@traced
def foo(a,b):
    if a == 0:
        return b
    return foo(b=a-1,a=b-1)
```

The desired output is something like this:

```python
foo(a=4, b=3)
foo(a=2, b=3)
foo(a=2, b=1)
foo(a=0, b=1)
```

Positional arguments need not be labeled. It is fine if only keyword arguments are labeled.

My best attempt so far is:

```python
import inspect
from functools import wraps

class TracedClass:
    def __init__(self, f):
        """
        `f` is a callable, such as the `print` function or
        """
        self.__f = f
    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        sig = inspect.signature(self.__f)
        bsig = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        print(bsig)
        try:
            rv = self.__f(*args,**kwargs)
            outcome = repr(str(rv))[1:-1]
            return rv
        except BaseException as exc:
            outcome = exc
            raise exc from None
        finally:
            outcome = repr(str(outcome))[1:-1]
            # print("`- "+outcome)
        
def traced(foo):
    new_foo = TracedClass(foo)
    new_foo = wraps(foo)(new_foo)
    return new_foo
            
@traced
def foo(a,b):
    if a==0:
        return b
    return foo(b=a-1,a=b-1)
    
foo(4, 5)
```

The current output output is incorrect:

```python
<BoundArguments (a=4, b=5)>
<BoundArguments (a=4, b=3)>
<BoundArguments (a=2, b=3)>
<BoundArguments (a=2, b=1)>
<BoundArguments (a=0, b=1)>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `inspect.stack()` contain the calling function name? Match that with the bound arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
print(bsig)
```

with

```
print(self.__f.__name__ + "(" + ", ".join(f"{key}={val}" for key, val in bsig.arguments.items()) + ")")
```

Here

```
self.__f.__name__
```

gives the name of the calling function, and

```
bsig.arguments
```

gives a dictionary of the arguments, so with some simple formatting we can write it as if you are calling the function.